# How to copy specific number of lines more in a file?

Tags: vim

I would like to copy `n` *more* number of lines in a file. At the moment, I am doing this indirectly: From current line `x`, I use `V<x+n>ggy` where `<x+n>` is substituted with the actual sum.

Is there a way to copy directly `n` more lines from current line?

Comment: On old venerable `vi` I used to perform `<n>yy`

Comment: why you put `gg` there? I don't know what do you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to go into visual mode (the `V`) for that. The normal mode `yy` command already takes a `[count]`, but that includes the current line. So for *n more lines*, you need to pass a `[count]` of n + 1. Example: Yank current and 2 more lines (total 3): `3yy`.

If you don't want to do the arithmetic, you can also use the `:yank` Ex command. The range there is specified as you want: current (`.`) until current plus n (`.+n`). Example: `:.,.+2yank`

---

Based on your preference to visual mode, and using `gg` instead of `G` to move to a line, it appears as if you're still new to Vim. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution myself while playing around. `n` more lines can be simply copied by using: `Vn+y`